# Make a post request to a remote PHP server containing base64 encoded data from a Fingerprint scanner capture using a Web Brouser

Tags: javascript, browser, fingerprint

I currently need an assistance on how to read data from a client fingerprint scanner using the Web Browser thereafter, make a POST request to a remote PHP server where verification can be conduct.

I am thinking if this can be achieved with JavaScript or probably any API services available for this purpose does exist? Please help out with possible solutions. Thanks in anticipation.

I have tried making a POST request to **m2sys API** using POSTMAN to register and verify base_encode64(fingerprint image) which is actually successful, I need a way to get the fingerprint image from the client browser directly from the scanner and make a POST request to a remote server.

Any possible solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to access the [fingerprint reader on mobile devices directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41765698/10304804). But there are some APIs that can be used for this kind of validation. The [Web Authentication API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API) mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63113555/10304804), can be used on mobile devices and the [WebUSB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebUSB_API) can be used if you have a fingerprint reader connected to the computer for example.